# How can I set Tomcat unloadDelay in a Spring Boot 2 application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

The default is 2000ms which isn't enough time for requests to complete cleanly in my application.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Is there any problem to put it in tomcat  context.xml ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that in a Spring Boot application. It seems to me that all of that is done programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Spring Booot 2, you can use:

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    tomcat.addContextCustomizers(context -> {
        if(context instanceof StandardContext) {
            ((StandardContext)context).setUnloadDelay(8000);
        }
    });
    return tomcat;
}
```

Before Spring Boot 2, [this was different](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#embedded-containers-package-structure) and you have to use a `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` instead of the `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` and `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` instead of `ServletWebServerFactory`.